# Does plotly offline offer the same as online version?

Tags: python, plotly

I am considering moving from `matplotlib` to `plotly`.

`plotly` seems great and all, but most of the documentation assumes that the user uses online API, not offline one. So, any example with the line

```
import plotly.plotly as py
```

needs to be converted to offline language somehow, using `plotly.offline`.

What I've noticed is the functionality of `plotly.offline` seems to be incomplete. First, `plotly.offline` cannot replace `plotly.plotly`. Also, there are some examples that only provides online versions of the code, like [this one](https://plot.ly/python/scattermapbox/) and [this one too](https://plot.ly/python/presentations-api/). They both seem to have no way to do that in offline mode, or at least I haven't found out how.

So, haven't I googled enough or is `plotly`'s offline functionality really incomplete?

Comment: If my suggestion helped you, would you consider marking it as the accepted answer?

Answer (score 1):

Late to the party, but I think you (and others) would like to know that some time after you posted your question, plotly was made ***available without the hassle of worrying about plotly offline***.

Since you're posting under the python tag, take a look at [Is Plotly for Python Free?](https://plot.ly/python/is-plotly-free/)

Note that:

> [...] Open Street Maps or Mapbox, [...] will need a connection to that service.

Also note that plotly still has commercial offerings such as [Dash Enterprise](https://plot.ly/dash/) and [Chart Studio Enterprise](https://plot.ly/online-chart-maker/).

Personally I'm using plotly with Jupyter Lab and think it's a fantastic combination.